# How to generate Authorization Bearer token using client ID , tenant Id, Client secret of azure AD using NodeJs for calling REST API?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am able to generate the token in Postman: using the following details.

```
tenant_id: 09872XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: d7b7e-ighewiojwoei9-868767
client_secret:adat-XXXXXX-diupi825tfsq38XXXXX
resource: https://management.azure.com/
```

Want to achieve the same using NodeJs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using is the [Azure AD client credential flow v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), to do this in node.js, you could use the [`ADAL for Node.js`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs#server-to-server-via-client-credentials), change the `resource` to `https://management.azure.com/`, the `applicationId` is the `client_id` you used.

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';
var tenant = 'myTenant.onmicrosoft.com'; // AAD Tenant name.
var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var applicationId = 'yourApplicationIdHere'; // Application Id of app registered under AAD.
var clientSecret = 'yourAADIssuedClientSecretHere'; // Secret generated for app. Read this environment variable.
var resource = 'https://management.azure.com/'; // URI that identifies the resource for which the token is valid.

var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, applicationId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(tokenResponse);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much this code was very useful and easily understandable.